# Taking Input in Java for unknown number of lines of Test Cases

Tags: java, input, bufferedreader

I was trying to solve a problem on www.spoj.com. The Program had the following statement.

"The input will contain several test cases (not more than 10). Each test case is a single line with a number n."
`0 <= n <= 1,000,000,000`

Is there a way I can take input from user for unknown test cases using `BufferedReader` class?

[Problem link](http://www.spoj.com/problems/COINS/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reader reaches the eof then it returns `-1` in case of `read()` method in `BufferedReader` but in case of `readLine()` method it returns `null`.So you can do it by following way:-

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String str="";
while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
{
    //It will ends when eof character will encounter
}
```

Above program will till end of program will be reached. Hope this will help you.